# Can Cloud Scheduler trigger by user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a function like: every user has `i=5` If play one game then `i--`

```
If i<5 then after 30min i++.
```

Is it possible to make this function using Scheduler?

Comment: Can you show an example of this somewhere?

Comment: Just like many of mobile game,when user play one game then minus some energy. And energy can restored by time.

Comment: If your question is "Is it possible?" the answer is yes. You can store the score after each game in the database, together with the timestamp, and run a Scheduled Function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions that checks the condition contained in your question and update the user's "energy" accordingly.

Comment: But I can't use schedule to check every second, So is it possible to trigger schedule by user or set a timer for 30min?

Comment: I guess that you don't want a trigger by player? In any case, you are limited to 100 scheduler per project, and each scheduler cost $0.1. Not sure that you want this, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an implementation of a resource generator. You don't need to generate resources on timers for each player - better way is to calculate the status of a resource when it's needed.

If you wish to learn more about this technique, this question has it answered.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/game-resource-timers-general-implementation

Comment: Thank's, I think I know how to make this function.